# Need help in upgrading/migrating Apache Tomcat/9.0.46 to Apache Tomcat/9.0.79 (latest available version)

Tags: tomcat

Need help and detailed steps for upgrading/migrating Apache Tomcat/9.0.46 to Apache Tomcat/9.0.79 (latest available version)

I looked into official tomcat migration guide, https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-9.html#Upgrading_9.0.x I didn't find the proper steps for upgrading/migrating.

Comment: What have you tried? 
Step 1: Unzip Tomcat 9.0.79, delete the 9.0.79 weapps folder copy webapps folder from 9.0.46 and start tomcat, post the errors